# Ubuntu 16.04 system event sound effect

Tags: sound

How to turn on system event sounds like desktop-login/logout, device-added/removed or windows-open/close/maximized/minimized?

I got the lightdm drums and geary new mail alert so how to turn on all the others?

There are system event sounds in root folders

```
ls /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu

index.theme  notifications  ringtones  stereo
```

Should at least play the login/logout sound because its there

```
ls /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo

bell.ogg               dialog-information.ogg   phone-outgoing-calling.ogg
button-pressed.ogg     dialog-question.ogg      service-login.ogg
button-toggle-off.ogg  dialog-warning.ogg       service-logout.ogg
button-toggle-on.ogg   message-new-instant.ogg  system-ready.ogg
desktop-login.ogg      message.ogg              window-slide.ogg
desktop-logout.ogg     phone-incoming-call.ogg
dialog-error.ogg       phone-outgoing-busy.ogg
```

I added some custom system event sounds at local folder but how to turn them on?

```
ls .local/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo

button-pressed.ogg        dialog-question.ogg      Startup1_1.ogg
button-toggle-off.ogg     dialog-warning.ogg       Startup1_2.ogg
button-toggle-on.ogg      Exit1_2.ogg              Startup1_3.ogg
desktop-login.ogg         K3b_success.ogg          system-ready.ogg
desktop-logout.ogg        Knock.ogg                trash-empty.ogg
desktop-switch-left.ogg   Kopete_status.ogg        window-close.ogg
desktop-switch-right.ogg  message-new-instant.ogg  window-maximized.ogg
device-added.ogg          phone-incoming-call.ogg  window-minimized.ogg
device-removed.ogg        phone-outgoing-busy.ogg  window-unmaximized.ogg
dialog-error.ogg          service-login.ogg        window-unminimized.ogg
dialog-information.ogg    service-logout.ogg
```

It is also strange to have two sound themes (freedesktop and ubuntu),

```
ls /usr/share/sounds/

alsa  freedesktop  speech-dispatcher  ubuntu
```

But in the sound settings GUI only one appears (default - educated guess,  it must be the one in sounds/ubuntu folder)

[Sound settings printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztEZU.png)

Anyone can point me the right direction on this?

Comment: Use MATE.  It has that by default. 

Comment: Dont like MATE much. It was good the MATE DE team to keep the gnome2 soul alive but they could evolve instead of remaining with a look from the past century.

Answer (score 1):

Solved ... although at the moment im running debian (sid) gnome3, i suppose the settings are similar for ubuntu.

dconf-editor > /org/gnome/desktop/sound/input-feedback-sounds

Changed "false" to "true"

And just because not all applications have completed the transition from gconf to dconf I have also changed

gconf-editor > /desktop/gnome/sounds

And tick the boxes "enable_esd", "event_sounds" and "input_feedback_sounds".

Also found this [sound naming specification](http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html) at freedesktop website and added some custom extra event sounds.

:) I made a .ogg file for all event sounds (all of them) using a text to speech app and now i have jarvis gnome :p

Some of them: [Low Battery](https://openload.co/embed/4nIadFDpNfo/battery-low_.mp3) | [Internet connection](https://openload.co/embed/vENeie17W9A/network-connectivity-established_.mp3) | [Internet disconnection](https://openload.co/embed/jEg2FW3klYQ/network-connectivity-lost.mp3)

Comment: Link Rot.  Those links don't go anywhere.  It would be best if you could post step-by-step instructions.